# Move and clone VirtualBox machines with filesystem commands

Tags: linux, virtualization, command-line-interface, virtualbox, cloning

I know of 2 ways to clone a VirtualBox machine on a linux host, one is by using the VirtualBox gui and exporting and re-importing as appliance (in the file menu of VirtualBox).

The other is by cloning only the virtual disk container files:

```
VBoxManage clonevdi /mnt/md1/original/root-fs.vdi /mnt/md1/cloned/root-fs.vdi
```

(Taken from http://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?p=853#p858 )

---

Edit: this does not seem to work for VDI files that are already part of ~/VirtualBox/VirtualBox.xml, I get an error message:

ERROR: Cannot register the hard disk '/mnt/md1/original/root-fs.vdi' with UUID {96a1462b-c30a-4911-a954-d9093122f083} because a hard disk '/mnt/md1/original/root-fs.vdi' with UUID {96a1462b-c30a-4911-a954-d9093122f083} already exists in the media registry ('/home/mit/.VirtualBox/VirtualBox.xml')

---

I would have to create a new VM afterwards and use the cloned virtual disk containers.

Is it also possible to clone a VM by copying the virtual disk contianer files and the config files using filesystem commands and do the rest by hand?

I'd have to manually edit the   ~/VirtualBox/VirtualBox.xml and insert a new disk and a new machine:

Can I just make up UUIDs or how would this work?

I would very much prefer this hardcore method of doing things as it allows me to freely and rapdily backup, restore, move or clone machines. Or ist there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can change the UUID of a vdi using the command

```
VBoxManage internalcommands setvdiuuid disk.vdi
```

or if you are using VBox V4.x at least to 4.0.10

```
 VBoxManage internalcommands sethduuid disk.vdi
```

then use the GUI  import the new 'unique' disk.

If you want to clone a particular VirtualBox machine then you are probably better off making an appliance of it and then using it. To make an appliance use the GUI Export Appliance feature or the `vboxmanage  export` command. The resultant appliance can then be imported using the GUI Import Appliance feature or the `vboxmanage import` command.

Comment: +1 million if I could. Note, in my version (4.x) this is "sethduuid", not "setvdiuuid".

Comment: @Mike: Cheers - updated to reflect changes

Answer (score 1):

Or you can edit the "Virtualbox.xml" setupfile with the right uuids for the machineid. Worked great for me moving a virtual machine from one host to another (both hosts being 64-bits linux, no idea if it had worked moving to e.g. windows or mac) see http://sickel.net/blogg/?p=1581 for details.

This works even if the vboxmanager on the original host for some reason can not be run.